# Call function by function pointer from array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I'm new to C and I'm trying to create an array of structs which contain a function pointer.

Calling the function (and accessing the members) from the struct directly works as expected, but accessing it from the array by looping through it doesn't (accessing the members works).

I've found a similar question already, but I would like to know why my program which I put together from various tutorials and posts crashes when I try to call my function by accessing the function from the array.

structs.h

```
typedef struct {
  char *functionId;
  void (*callback)(unsigned char *data);
  char *name;
  char *description;
} Function;

typedef struct {
  Function *fArr;
  size_t used;
  size_t size;
} Array;
```

main.c

```
   #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "structs.h" 

   Array functionArray;

void function1(int *i){
    printf("PRINT: %d\n", i);
}

void function2(char *c[]){
    printf("PRINT: %s\n", c);
}

void addFunction(Function f){
    insertFunctionArray(&functionArray, f);
}

int main()
{
    initFunctionArray(&functionArray, 5);

    //create new struct for function and assign function to callback member
    Function fun;
    fun.name = "Function1";
    fun.functionId = "FUNCTION1";
    fun.description = "Description for Function 1";
    fun.callback = &function1; // <-- doesn't seem to matter if I assign it as a value or as a pointer?!

    Function fun2;
    fun2.name = "Function2";
    fun2.functionId = "FUNCTION2";
    fun2.description = "Description for Function 2";
    fun2.callback = &function2;

    fun2.callback("{fun:\"test\"}");

    fun.callback(17);

    //store functions in array
    addFunction(fun);
    addFunction(fun2);

    unsigned int i = 0;
    for(i; i<functionArray.used; i++)
      {
        printf("PRINT: %s\n", functionArray.fArr[i].functionId); // <-- this works
        functionArray.fArr[i].callback("777"); // <-- this doesn't work
        }
      }

    return 0;
}

void initFunctionArray(Array *fa, size_t initialSize) {
  fa->fArr = (Function *)malloc(initialSize * sizeof(Function));
  fa->used = 0;
  fa->size = initialSize;
  unsigned int i = 0;
  for(i; i<initialSize; i++)
      {
          memset(&fa->fArr[i],0,sizeof(Function));
      }
}

void insertFunctionArray(Array *fa, Function f) {
  if (fa->used == fa->size) {
    fa->size *= 2;
    fa->fArr = (Function *)realloc(fa->fArr, fa->size * sizeof(Function));
  }
  // Copy name
  fa->fArr[fa->used].name = (char*)malloc(strlen(f.name) + 1);
      strcpy(fa->fArr[fa->used].name, f.name);
  // Copy ID
  fa->fArr[fa->used].functionId=f.functionId;
  fa->used++;
}
```

Thanks & BR

Comment: Have you studied how to create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))?  It doesn't immediately look like you have.  _[…time passes…]_ On a second glance, it is clear you haven't — you have a type `Event` in the `Array` struct that is not defined in the code.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to remove that one. It should be working code now.

Comment: The code does not compile without excruciating errors. `error: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Werror=format=]
     printf("PRINT: %d\n", i);` etc.  You can't assign `function1` and `function2` to the same function pointer type.  You need to rethink what you're up to.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler-- [this link that you provided](http://sscce.org/) should be required reading for question posters on SO. Thanks for this!

Comment: @DavidBowling: the SSCCE link existed for a while before the MCVE link was created.  Since MCVE is a pointer on-site (to Stack Overflow), it the most used one.  Also, in comments, if you type `[MCVE]`, you get [MCVE], which is easy.  I often use "please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE])", which is entered as `please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE])`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code reworks the functions to take a `void *` and then, in the absence of the fix, crashes convincingly because of the trivial problem that you don't assign the `callback` when you copy the `Function` in `insertFunctionArray()`.  The fix is simple — assign the callback:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    char *functionId;
    void (*callback)(void *data);
    char *name;
    char *description;
} Function;

typedef struct
{
    Function *fArr;
    size_t used;
    size_t size;
} Array;

void initFunctionArray(Array *fa, size_t initialSize);
void insertFunctionArray(Array *fa, Function f);

Array functionArray;

static void function1(void *vp)
{
    int *i = vp;
    printf("PRINT: %d\n", *i);
}

static void function2(void *vp)
{
    char *s = vp;
    printf("PRINT: %s\n", s);
}

static void addFunction(Function f)
{
    insertFunctionArray(&functionArray, f);
}

int main(void)
{
    initFunctionArray(&functionArray, 5);

    // create new struct for function and assign function to callback member
    Function fun;
    fun.name = "Function1";
    fun.functionId = "FUNCTION1";
    fun.description = "Description for Function 1";
    fun.callback = &function1; // <-- doesn't seem to matter if I assign it as a value or as a pointer?!

    Function fun2;
    fun2.name = "Function2";
    fun2.functionId = "FUNCTION2";
    fun2.description = "Description for Function 2";
    fun2.callback = &function2;

    fun2.callback("{fun:\"test\"}");

    int v = 17;
    fun.callback(&v);

    // store functions in array
    addFunction(fun);
    addFunction(fun2);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < functionArray.used; i++)
    {
        printf("PRINT: %s (%p)\n", functionArray.fArr[i].functionId, (void *)functionArray.fArr[i].callback);
        functionArray.fArr[i].callback("777");
    }

    return 0;
}

void initFunctionArray(Array *fa, size_t initialSize)
{
    fa->fArr = (Function *)malloc(initialSize * sizeof(Function));
    fa->used = 0;
    fa->size = initialSize;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < initialSize; i++)
    {
        memset(&fa->fArr[i], 0, sizeof(Function));
    }
}

void insertFunctionArray(Array *fa, Function f)
{
    if (fa->used == fa->size)
    {
        fa->size *= 2;
        fa->fArr = (Function *)realloc(fa->fArr, fa->size * sizeof(Function));
    }
    // Copy name
    fa->fArr[fa->used].name = (char *)malloc(strlen(f.name) + 1);
    strcpy(fa->fArr[fa->used].name, f.name);
    // Copy ID
    fa->fArr[fa->used].functionId = f.functionId;
    // Fix!
    fa->fArr[fa->used].callback = f.callback;
    fa->used++;
}
```

Output:

```
PRINT: {fun:"test"}
PRINT: 17
PRINT: FUNCTION1 (0x10c724af0)
PRINT: 3618615
PRINT: FUNCTION2 (0x10c724ad0)
PRINT: 777
```

Note: the code compiles cleanly on macOS Sierra 10.12.2 with GCC 6.2.0 (must upgrade!) using the command line:

```
$  gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition str19.c -o str19
```

---

#### Other changes

The `callback` function pointer was revised to take a `void *` argument instead of `unsigned char *`.  The two callback functions, `function1` and `function2` were made to match the callback interface — they take a `void *` argument and convert it to an appropriate type.  There was an extra level of indirection on `function2` that went by the wayside.  The direct call to `function1` via the `fun.callback` structure had to be changed; you can't pass the address of a simple numeric constant.  (You could use a 'compound literal', I suppose: `fun.callback(&(int){ 17 });`.)  I needed `<string.h>` to declare `strlen()`.

Pretty much everything else was unchanged.

Note that one of the first things I did was add the function pointer address to the printing operation before it was called.  When I got `0x0`, it didn't take long to find out what the trouble was.

Note that both `function1` and `function2` end up being called with `"777"` as the argument.  That's why I got `3618615` as the output from `function1` inside the loop.  That's not good — (un)fortunately, C is tolerant of such mistakes.

Note too that the code leaks a lot of memory.  It's more or less an MCVE, so that is more or less excusable.

Comment: Thank you that's it... It's really trivial as you say, but I was looking in the wrong places because of the extra things you have to take care of in C.

Comment: When you're working with pointers, one of the easiest things to check is that the pointers aren't null.  You can use `#include <assert.h>` at the top and `assert(pointer);` at appropriate locations — though I would use `assert(pointer != 0);` or `assert(pointer != NULL);` because I think it is easier to read.  When accessing `functionArray.fArr[i].callback("777")`, you could `assert(functionArray.fArr != NULL);` and `assert(functionArray.fArr[i].callback != NULL);`, for example. And, in some context, you might even `assert(i >= 0 && i < functionArray.used);`.  In this case, `i` is constrained.